# Try to use FOR XML Path with an except

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to print a result in one line instead of multiple lines. 
I have a query looks like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT  RTRIM(LTRIM(MACHNAME))
  FROM MACHS
  WHERE MACHID <> 0

EXCEPT 

SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(MACHNAME))
                 FROM GROUPS
                WHERE GROUPS.GROUPTYPE = 'M'
```

By using the Except query, I have :

> lineNumber MachName
>
> 1 WinMach2
>
> 2 WinMach6

And I would like to have :

> WinMach2, WinMach6

So, to print the result in one line, I tried :

```
select stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(MACHNAME))
  FROM MACHS
  WHERE MACHID <> 0

EXCEPT 

SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(MACHNAME))
                 FROM GROUPS
                WHERE GROUPS.GROUPTYPE = 'M' 
                for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 2, '') as machineName
              FROM GROUPS
```

But, The error is :

> The FOR XML clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, and subqueries when they contain a set operator. To work
>   around, wrap the SELECT containing a set operator using derived table
>   syntax and apply FOR XML on top of it.

It's working if I do  :

```
select stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(MACHNAME)) FROM MACHS WHERE MACHID <> 0
for xml path ('')), 1, 2, '') as machineName
FROM MACHS
```

The result is:

> WinMach1, WinMach2, WinMach3, WinMach4,
>   WinMach5, WinMach6, WinMach7, WinMach8,
>   WinMach9

I checked this : [SQL UNION FOR XML name output column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311198/sql-union-for-xml-name-output-column). But, I wasn't able to understand the fix.

And I tried : [Using UNION ALL in STUFF / XML Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165486/using-union-all-in-stuff-xml-path/9165622)
But, when I did the first part:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(MACHNAME))
  FROM MACHS
  WHERE MACHID <> 0

EXCEPT 

SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(MACHNAME))
                 FROM GROUPS
                WHERE GROUPS.GROUPTYPE = 'M') AS K
```

The error is 'No column name was specified for column 1 of 'K'.

Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `FROM` clause. So, you need to specify data source - in your case it is `AS K`, but it should be `DS ([k])` meaning alias of data source `DS` with column(s) - `K`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(MACHNAME))
    FROM MACHS
    WHERE MACHID <> 0
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(MACHNAME))
    FROM GROUPS
    WHERE GROUPS.GROUPTYPE = 'M'
) DS (K);
```

and the final like this:

```
select stuff
(
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(MACHNAME)) 
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(MACHNAME))
            FROM MACHS
            WHERE MACHID <> 0
            EXCEPT 
            SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(MACHNAME))
            FROM GROUPS
            WHERE GROUPS.GROUPTYPE = 'M'
        ) DS (MACHNAME)
        for xml path ('')
    )
    ,1
    ,2
    , ''
) as machineName
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` instead :

```
select stuff( (select distinct ',' +rtrim(ltrim(m.MACHNAME))
               from MACHS m
               where MACHID <> 0 and
                     not exists (select 1 
                                 from GROUPS g 
                                 where g.MACHNAME = m.MACHNAME and 
                                       g.GROUPTYPE = 'M'
                                ) for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as MachName
```